# centering ul so that columns will be centered too

Tags: html, css, html-lists

In my page I want it so that when you resize the page past the point of the pictures, that the pictures will go into another row, all the way so each picture has it's own row. And then potentially I won't need any media queries. But unfortunaltely I can't find a way to center. I have tried everything I can think of, aside of making hundreds of media queries with different positioning. I can't make it a block because then it won't go into rows, I have tried margin: 0 auto;. I have tried changing the padding, I have even tried using the html align="center". Nothing is working. Here is the website http://spencedesign.netau.net/singaporehome.html Also I have a minor issue, sorry to croud this with two questions. But when it is in it's mobile state, there is no 10px padding at the bottom, and the singapore title is on the left side rather than floating. Here is my code

```
    <html>
<head>
<title> Singapore - Home </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">

<style>
*  
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
body
{
  background: url('woodbackground.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;

}

#container 
{
  width: 90%; 
  margin: 0 auto;

}

h1 
{
  font: bold 65px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
  text-align: center; 
  color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}

h3
{
  font: 25px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; 
  text-align: center; 
  color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;

}

ul#gallery
{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 175px;
  width: 1300px;
}

ul#gallery li a
{
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 10px 25px 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px #333;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

ul#gallery li a:hover
{
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;

}

ul#gallery li a img
{
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;

}

ul#gallery li a p
{
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;

}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
  
{

  ul#gallery
{
  left: 2.2%;
  width: 600px;
}
  ul#gallery li a:hover
{
  top: 0px;
}
}


</style>
<body>

<div id="container">

   <h1> Singapore </h1>

     <h3><i> Singapore is the worlds first machine that works </i>- Lee Kuan Yew </h3>

<ul id="gallery">

  <li><a href="#"> <img src="gallery.jpg" alt="gallery" /> <p> Gallery </p> </a></li>


  <li><a href="#"> <img src="facts.jpg" alt="facts" /> <p> Facts </p></a></li>


  <li><a href="#"> <img src="tour.jpg" alt="tour" /> <p> Tour </p></a></li>


  <li><a href="#"> <img src="author.jpg" alt="author" /> <p> Author </p> </a></li>

</ul>
<br/>
</div><!-- Container -->


</body>
<html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive checked your link and simply adding `text-align:center;` to your container will make the `ul`s centered (because you have them as inline elements)

```
#container 
{
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of floating those items, you should instead ensure that the items use `display: inline-block`. Then you can set `text-align: center` on the parent element.

Here is a testcase that shows the effect http://oksushi.com/test/centered-tabs/

Comment: I think that would work, if my links were text, but since they are image and text it doesn't